# mysql round-off error and aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, rounding

I have this table for the orders

```
+-----+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   id|order_id|   price|        tax|       qty |
+-----+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|    5|     123|  231.40|      50.91|          1|
+-----+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|    6|     123|  210.74|      46.36|          1|
+-----+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

and this query for getting the results for the order 123

```sql
SELECT Sum(price * qty)               AS tot_sub,
       ( Sum(( price + tax ) * qty) ) AS tot
FROM   products
WHERE  order_id = 123
```

and this is the results

```
+-------+-----------------+
|tot_sub|tot              |
+-------+-----------------+
|442.14 |539.4100000000001|
+-------+-----------------+
```

I'm expecting a perfect value for `tot` (`539.41`)

I know that the internal representation of floating point numbers (in general) can have some errors, and differs from the exact theoretical number.

In this case, can I write a better query for avoiding this error without using the ROUND function?

thanks

Comment: What are the data types of price, tax, and qty?

Comment: Don't fix this in the query, fix this in your data - Use decimals when you need exact decimal values.

Comment: int, int and ...varchar. Here is the problem, I've changed to int and now I get the expected results. Thanks

Comment: @Infrid - I can't believe that you `price` and `tax` values are `int` as you have said.  You can't store `231.40` in a `int` and you wouldn't get the rounding errors.

Comment: sorry, I meant decimal(8,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cast as decimal`.

Change:

```
SELECT Sum(price * qty) AS tot_sub,
       ( Sum(( price + tax ) * qty) ) AS tot
FROM   products
WHERE  order_id = 123
```

To:

```
SELECT Sum(price * qty) AS tot_sub,
       Sum( ( cast( price as decimal(10,2) ) 
            + cast( tax   as decimal(10,2) ) ) * qty ) AS tot
FROM   products
WHERE  order_id = 123
```

***Refer to***:

- [**MySQL: CAST(expr AS type)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

  - The CAST() function takes an expression of any type and produces a result value of a specified type.

Comment: Depending on values, it may be prudent to cast to DECIMAL *before* multiplying by the quantity.

Comment: That may cause pre rounding, if value for quantity field is high.

Comment: The most resilient would be `(CAST(a AS DECIMAL(10,2)) + CAST(b AS DECIMAL(10,2))) * c`.  Multiplying then casting multiplies any error up, risking it becoming significant enough to to change the result of the cast.  If the error is significant enough to have that effect *before* multiplying by the quantity *(your suggested pre-rounding)* then it will still be present *after* multiplying by quantity.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Sum(price * qty)               AS tot_sub,
       Round( Sum(( price + tax ) * qty) ),2) AS tot
FROM   products
WHERE  order_id = 123
```